# Ceasar Cipher method of decryption isn't working and is printing nothing

Tags: java, encryption, intellij-idea, caesar-cipher

I am very new to programming and can't figure out the issue with my Cesar cipher my method for encryption works fine but my method for decryption is not working.

Main class

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public ceasarCipher ceasarCipher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        com.company.ceasarCipher utilityClass = new ceasarCipher();
        int inShift;
        String inString;
        String encryptedString = "";

        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string to encrypt");
        inString = sca.nextLine();

        System.out.println("=======================================================================================");
        System.out.println("In this program");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to encrypt your string by shifting it forward a certain amount");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to decipher your string by shifting it backwards a certain amount");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to give you all possible combinations of the shift in order to decipher");
        System.out.println("Press 4 to exit the program");
        System.out.println("=======================================================================================");

        while(!sca.hasNext("x") && !sca.hasNext("X")){

            int userInput;
            userInput = sca.nextInt();

            switch (userInput){

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount greater than 0 that you would like your String to be shifted forwards in order to encrypt it");
                    inShift = sca.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(utilityClass.ccEncrypt(inShift,inString));
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount greater than 0 that you would like your String to be shifted backwards in order to decipher it");
                    inShift = sca.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(utilityClass.ccDecipher(inShift,encryptedString));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Subclass with methods

```
package com.company;

/**
 * Created by Jake on 14/04/2017.
 */
public class ceasarCipher {

    private int maxVal = 26;

    //private int inShift;
    //private String inString;
    private String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    public String ccEncrypt (int inShift, String inString) {

        String encryptedString = "";
        char modulo;
        int pos;

        inString = inString.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {

            pos = letters.indexOf(inString.charAt(i));

            modulo = this.letters.charAt((pos + inShift) % maxVal);

            encryptedString += modulo;
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String ccDecipher (int inShift, String encryptedString) {

        String decipheredString = "";
        char modulo;
        int pos;

        for (int i = encryptedString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            pos = letters.indexOf(encryptedString.charAt(i));

            modulo = this.letters.charAt((pos - inShift) % maxVal);

            decipheredString += modulo;
        }
        return decipheredString;
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void ccDecipherAll (String inString){

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"printing nothing"*? Does it at least print "Please enter a string to encrypt"? If so, please [edit] your question to show the actual output along with your inputs.

Comment: Yes it does to be more specific it isnt printing my decryption method in case 2

Comment: So, you enter the ciphertext and then the program ends? This looks like an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException situation where weston's answer is the appropriate way to solve that. Do you see this exception anywhere? Look closely.

Comment: i haven't seen it yet and it doesn't end, theres just nothing there. if I change the decipheredString = null it sometimes prints out just null. What exactly is an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException as I don't think I have an array.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just an IndexOutOfBoundsException as shown in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: Hint: simply put the exception name into Google. For each of those basic things there is a lot of documentation available.

Comment: @GhostCat Reopened, the dupe didn't make sense. OP hasn't mentioned an NPE.

Comment: Still can't figure it out I think it might be an NPE but not sure

Comment: @weston He had npe put in now deleted comments twice...

Comment: Hint: where exactly are you assigning the user input to `encryptedString`?

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything to `encryptedString`. You should use `inString` perhaps.

```
System.out.println(utilityClass.ccDecipher(inShift, inString));
```

And if you want to do this in a loop, you might want to update that `inString` each time:

```
inString = utilityClass.ccDecipher(inShift, inString); //same for encrypt
System.out.println(inString);
```

Then, modulo of a negative doesn't do what you want it to:

Make:

```
(pos - inShift) % maxVal
```

Into:

```
(pos - (inShift % maxVal) + maxVal) % maxVal
```

To ensure you're not taking modulo of a negative.

You're also decoding in a backwards order.